# How do I reverse the URL of a Django admin template in a view?

Tags: django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have a custom Django admin form registered, how do I programmatically find the URL for the template in a view?

I know my form is at `/admin/custom_app/horse/` but how do I programmatically look that up, incase the from URL is changed in the future?

Here's how the form is registered:

```
admin.site.register(Horse, HorseAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine the `url_name` of the form. Use the relative address of where the form is, and find the name using `resolve` like so:

```
In [1]: from django.urls import resolve 
    ...: match = resolve('/admin/custom_app/horse/') 
    ...: match.url_name 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[1]: 'custom_app_horse_changelist'
```

Now you can use `reverse` to look up the URL, just remember to prefix `admin:` to it like so:

```
In [63]: from django.urls import reverse 
    ...: reverse('admin:custom_app_horse_changelist')                                                                                                                           
Out[63]: '/admin/custom_app/horse/'
```